# Keyboard not working in Samung Tizen TV emulator

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

[Samsung Tizen TV Keyboard Guide](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/user-interaction/keyboardime/)

From the above link, it says that Virtual keyboard will appear when we focus on an input or textarea. I tried allmost all guides & samples to make a keyboard appear on the simulator, its not working at all.
Do i need to add any privilege in config.xml or any settings i should  change?!

**Environment**

```
MAC OS Mojave 10.14.2         
Tizen studio 3.0
```

**Simulator Details**

```
Device Model = tizen-2.2 build.
Manufacturer = Tizen
Build Version = TIZEN_WEB_SIMULATOR_000001
```

[Simulator Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVHvN.png)
[Tizen Simulator version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDBr1.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Inputting text in simulator works like in normal browser on PC.
If you want to have IME displayed, you need to use emulator or TV device.

According to the documentation, usage of simulator is very limited, it is recommended for quick prototype development,  TV-specific modules are not supported.

Full simulator description can be found here: https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-simulator